# mongodb + nodejs данные для авторизации

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Подскажите, насколько безопасно сохранять данные для авторизации в mongodb посредством конфига, который находится в ноде. Для подключения использую нативный драйвер.

То есть, есть пользователь, который читает данные из базы, я его пароль беру из конфига и подключаюсь. Не знаю как защититься.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начни хранить данные логина/пароля в бд, в отдельной табличке.
При попытке логина ищи по логину, если найден, сравнивай пароль (еще лучше будет, если захешируешь пароль и соль будет отдельным столбцом), если сравнение прошло успешно - выдаешь данные, если нет - бросаешь ошибку.